# Unable to display mysql query result in the browser with axios in react

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, axios

I was trying to retrieve data from database and display it in the browser on button click but I always receive this error (`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {studentId, firstName, surName, otherName, state, localGovt, phoneNumber, imgUrl}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`). I was able to see the data when I use `console.log`, but failed in the DOM.

Here is the code on the frontend.

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SearchUsers = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [studentResult, setStudentResult] = useState([]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    //const sanitizedInput = input.trim().toUpperCase();

    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3500/students");
      const { result } = data; // this is an array
      console.log(result)//this works. it displays array of objects with the data from the db
        setStudentResult(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col w-2/4 mx-auto my-20">
        <div>
          <input
            className="input w-full"
            type="text"
            name="search"
            placeholder="Search a Student"
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center mt-5">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn shadow shadow-gray-500"
            onClick={handleSearch}
          >
            Get All Students
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          {studentResult.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <p>{item.firstName}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default SearchUsers;
```

Here is code on the backend. It's a controller function that retrieves all data from the database

```
const getAllStudents = (req, res) => {
  const selectAll = "SELECT * FROM students";

  studentDB.query(selectAll, (err, result) => {
    res.sendStatus(200).json({ result: result });
  });
};
```

Comment: use object here instead of array `const [studentResult, setStudentResult] = useState([]);` in `useState([])`

Comment: If I use an object instead of an array I cannot iterate through it using `Array.map()` function as I was trying to do. And it was what the error message was complaining about. Or maybe I don't understand what you meant.

Comment: what was the result of `studentResult`?

Comment: The data retrieved from db was an array of objects with `string` keys and `string` values like `[{studentId: "someId", firstName:"someName", lastName:"someName"}]` etc... which I was trying to pass to `studentResult` and the iterate through it with `Array.map()` in the DOM

Comment: what was your expected output?

Comment: To see the result in the browser on button click.

Comment: so print using `{item.firstName}` instead of `{item}`

Comment: It did but the studentResult does not seem to have the data from the result passed to it. That the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's going wrong?

The problem arises when you:

1. Initialize `useState` with an empty array, and
2. Didn't define its type;

Then, the type of array will implicitly be assigned to `never[]`, meaning that array should always be empty.

Therefore, mutating that array, including via `setStudentResult(newArray)`, will always fail.

#### How to fix it

To solve this, we need to explicitly define the type of the empty array. For example:

```
const [studentResult, setStudentResult] = useState<{name: string, grade:number}[]>([]);
```

You should change the type declaration above based on the data structure of `result`.

Hope it helps. Cheers.